# Any other language for creating apps in "lower end" mobiles apart from J2ME?

Tags: java-me, substitution

I use J2ME for developing mobile apps for lower end phones. We prefer lower end phones because we target on medical apps that will be in reach of even the people who can afford a basic phone that supports Java. I find many limitations in J2ME, like text fields cannot be resized. There is no support for entering "DOUBLE/FLOAT" in text boxes. Ex - xyz.NUMERIC in J2ME only allows numerical values but not floating or decimal point values. Is there any other language with which we can develop apps that can run on a lower end Java phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but you might want to look into LWUIT (Light Weight User Interface Toolkit).

https://lwuit.java.net/

It may solve many of your problems.